# OperationalError at /1 no such column: auctions_comment.listing_id

Tags: python, html, django, web, django-models

I'm new to Django. i'm trying to display all the comments for a listing in an auction site
Help me find a way to display all the comments for a listing.

**Mosdels.py**

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64, default="")
    starting_bid = models.CharField(max_length=64, default="$")
    description = models.TextField(default="")
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="")
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Comment(models.Model):
    comment = models.TextField(default="")
    listing = models.ForeignKey(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="comments", default="")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="comments", default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user} - {self.listing}"
```

**views.py**

```
def listing(request, listing_id):
    listing = Listing.objects.get(pk=listing_id)
    comments = listing.comments.all()
    return render(request, "auctions/listing.html", {
        "listing":listing,
        "comments":comments

    })
```

Comment: Have you run `makemigrations/migrate`?

Comment: yes I have done that

Comment: Are you sure? The error strongly suggests that you haven't applied a migration that adds the `Comment.listing` field

Comment: I'm positive. I even did it again just to be sure

Answer (score 0):

_If you are trying to display in a template you can use something like following:

```
{% for listing_item in listing %}
  <div>{{listing_item.title}}

  {% for comment in listing_item.comment_set.all %}
  <div>{{comment}}</div>
  {% endfor %}

  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

EDIT: If only sending the one listing from your view:

```
{{listing.title}}
{% for comment in listing.comment_set.all %}
  <div>{{comment}}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

EDIT2: Noticed you have a related name there.

```
{{listing.title}}
{% for comment in listing.comments.all %}
  <div>{{comment}}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: do i need to change my views.py to use this code?

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice you only send one listing. Take the outer for loop out of my code.

Comment: Although I agree with Iain - that error points to a migration that hasn't run.

Comment: I promise you i've been running makemigrations/migrate over and over again. it says no changes detected, no migrations to apply

Comment: I think i've figured it out. even when i make changes and run makemigrations/migrate, it says no changes detected. so something is wrong and it's not in the code